# How to sort a Collection of Objects?

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a class `Gym` which contains the following fields:

```
private int id;

private String name;

private String street;

private String housenumber;

private String zipcode;

private String lat;

private String lng;

private String city;
```

All of the data is in a database. A user can filter gyms by some creteria: sports and distance. I have a function which gets all of the gyms out of the database and adds them to a layout.

The `lat` and `lng` fields also are in the database.

When a user requests all the gyms the distance between the user and the position is calculated using the following code:

```
double distance = Math.round(gpsHelper.calculateDistance(location.getLatitude(), Double.valueOf(gym.getLat()),
                location.getLongitude(), Double.valueOf(gym.getLng()), 0.0, 0.0));
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String formattedDistance = "Afstand: " + String.valueOf(df.format(distance)) + " km";
```

What I would like to do is the following: I would like to sort all the gyms by their distance to the user. So sort them by `df.format(distance)`.

Could anyone give me a push into the right direction? I think I've added al the relevant code.

Comment: can you simplify your example may be? like something smaller and easily verifiable?

Comment: If you have a list of Gyms (List<Gym>, then you should override compareTo in the Gym class (that is, your Gym class should implement the Comparable interface).

Comment: "sort it by every uneven index" - care to explain what that's meant to be? Basically, if you have a `List<Gym> list` you'd sort it via `Collections.sort(list, someComparator)` where `someComparator` is an implementation of `Comparator<Gym>`. (You could also make `Gym` implement `Comparable` but that would only allow you to sort by one exact order, e.g. name _or_ distance. If you need either of them or both you'd need a comparator).

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you're trying to do?  Your question reads: "I have this Java function... I'm trying to sort them by distance".  What is *them*, specifically?  And I don't just mean "the gyms" - which variable do you wish to appear in sorted order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Collections.sort

[**`Collections.sort(List<T> list)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements.

For example:

```
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>();

fruits.add("Pineapple");
fruits.add("Apple");
fruits.add("Orange");
fruits.add("Banana");

Collections.sort(fruits);

int i=0;
for(String temp: fruits){
    System.out.println("fruits " + ++i + " : " + temp);
}
```

Will give as output:

```
fruits 1 : Apple
fruits 2 : Banana
fruits 3 : Orange
fruits 4 : Pineapple
```

<sub>See other examples at: [Java object sorting example (Comparable and Comparator)](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/).</sub>

## Comparator

[**`Comparator`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is a comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects. Comparators can be passed to a sort method (such as [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) or [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[]))) to allow precise control over the sort order.

```
Collections.sort(people, new Comparator<Person>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return o1.getLastName().compareTo(o2.getLastName());
    }
});
```

## Lambda Expressions

Java 8 introduced [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)'s equivalent is:

```
Comparator<Person> people =
    (Person o1, Person o2)->o1.getLastName().compareTo(o2.getLastName());
```